# Converting from Eclipse PDT to Vim

Tags: php, eclipse, vim, eclipse-pdt

I truly love VIM - it's one of only a handful of applications I've every come across that make you feel warm and fuzzy inside.  However, for PHP development, I still use PDT Eclipse although I would love to switch.

The reason I can't quite at the moment is the CTRL+SPACE code-assist functionality that I rely on so much - it's so useful, especially when type hinting, or using PHPDoc variable comment blocks.

I know there are cool plugins for VIM out there that can probably replicate this functionality and then some - but what are they?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vim has [OmniCompletion](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/version7.html#new-omni-completion) built in, you should add this to your .vimrc:

```
filetype plugin on
au FileType php set omnifunc=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
```

In addition I recommend you this plugins:

- [VTreeExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=184)
- [snippetsEmu](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1318)

and also take a look to this [article](http://tech.blog.box.net/2007/06/20/how-to-debug-php-with-vim-and-xdebug-on-linux/) about php debugging in Vim, and this [paper](http://www.scribd.com/doc/263139/VIM-for-PHP-Programmers), it has many useful tips for using Vim in PHP Development.

Comment: your last link to a scribd.com paper has been taken down :( I hope a replacement link is available!

Comment: @Derek: You can find it [here](http://zmievski.org/2007/02/vim-for-php-programmers-slides-and-resources), sorry for the delayed response, I haven't noticed your comment until now, when someone up-voted my answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Code assist it's a new feature of VIM 7
[Ctrl+x] [Ctrl+o] will auto complete your code or open a popup of options

More features of VIM 7 can be found in this [blogpost](http://linuxhelp.blogspot.com/2006/09/visual-walk-through-of-couple-of-new.html)

Btw, I too like vim, but the PDT (and other IDEs) has much more features than code assist that make me preffer them over it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [SuperTab](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1643) for making tab-autocompletion in Vim a bit easier to use than the standard bindings.  You may also want to look into ctags, if you're into code indexing.  [Google "php vim ctags"](http://www.google.com/search?q=vim+ctags+php) and you'll see plenty of articles describing how to set it up.

The official Vim Wiki has a [PHP section](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1643) with some good tips, like integrating the official PHP documentation.