# As a C# developer who wants to do some PHP work, what [book/online articles] should I [buy/read] to introduce myself to PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got the bare minimum to handle the Linux/MySQL parts of the stack, but I want to have a basic grasp of PHP before I dive in.  I'll be working on WordPress plugins, in case there's anything specifically interesting for that.

PS - any recommendations regarding recommended source control/IDEs would also be great, but I guess that's a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're developing C# you should definitely take a look at [VS.Php](http://www.jcxsoftware.com)

Answer (score 6):

I would recomment the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/) too!

Answer (score 3):

For PHP books you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90924/what-is-the-best-php-programming-book) question, personally I like [Programming PHP](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596006815/), IDEs, I can recommend you to try:

- [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/)
- [Zend Studio for Eclipse](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/)
- [NetBeans for PHP](http://php.netbeans.org/)
- [DevPHP](http://devphp.sourceforge.net/)
- [Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202685/converting-from-eclipse-pdt-to-vim)

Vim actually it's not an IDE, but you can get omnicompletion, syntax coloring, debugging, and so on...

The [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/) it's also a really good place to start learning the language.

Answer (score 0):

The best php/mysql book is probably [PHP and MySQL web development](http://ibmdw.safaribooksonline.com/9780672329166) but if you already have an experience in web development you might just need something like the [PHP cookbook](http://safari.oreilly.com/0596101015).

Also, if you don't have any experience with share hosting, you should read something like [Apache security](http://ibmdw.safaribooksonline.com/0596007248) (chapter 6).